# How to add newline to Stringformat with Datetime

Tags: c#, wpf, newline, string-formatting, axis

I'm trying to split my date-labels in my axis. So that one tick is not "12:00:00 03.07.2017" in one line. 
I'm trying to get two lines:

"12:00:00

03.07.2017"

I Need to modify the StringFormat codebehind. I already tried `StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss&#x0a;dd.MM.yyyy"` but no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: `StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss'\r\n'dd.MM.yyyy";`

Comment: In C# you can write: `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss\r\ndd.MM.yyyy")` without quotation mark.

Comment: "HH:mm:ss'\r\n'dd.MM.yyyy" - worked for me - thanks

Comment: It's better to use `System.Environment.NewLine` constant instead of `\r\n`. As mentioned in @DineshSingh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm:ss\&#x0a;dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
```

Comment: '0:HH:mm:ss\&#x0a;dd.MM.yyyy' was good enough for me (mention the extra backslash). Actually, the extra braces gave an extra error.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss"+System.Environment.NewLine+"dd.MM.yyyy";
```